# Look up field shows [object Object] on view

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

My list is custom code, which has a look up field to another list on same site.
But when I create items, this field displayed as [object Object] on view (in display form, it still displays normally).

I tried create new look up field through List settings, the new field works properly.

So why the look up field displays as [object Object] on view?

UPDATE:
This is my code

```
helper.AddField(new LookupFieldCreator(Constant.InternalName.Group.mail_group, Constant.DisplayName.Group.MailGroup){
           ShowInDisplayForm = true,
           ShowInEditForm = true,
           ShowInNewForm = true,
           LookupList = Constant.ListName.Header,
           LookupField = Constant.InternalName.Header.HeadHeader
       });
```

LookupFieldCreator is our method to create new Lookup Field.

Comment: Please attach your current code to you post. To me it looks like your are not exapnding the SPFieldLookupValue correctly before rendering it

Comment: @RobertLindgren I updated my post, I just use normal LookupList and LookupField attributes.

Comment: Does the view have JSLink attached to it?

Comment: No, just normal view. Even standard All Items view this error occurs.